# Remove Color in ImageMagick

Tags: php, imagemagick

It may be simple question, I have using ImageMagick with php code. The below command is working fine.

exec("convert audi_png.png -bordercolor white -border 1x1 -alpha set -channel RGBA -fuzz 20% -fill none -floodfill +0+0 white -shave 1x1 piechart-logo.png");

But i have only hexadecimal color code "#A52A2A". How to i user this code and remove the color in that image. Please help me.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
exec("convert audi_png.png -bordercolor \"#A52A2A\" -border 1x1 -alpha set -channel RGBA -fuzz 20% -fill none -floodfill +0+0 \"#A52A2A\" -shave 1x1 piechart-logo.png");
```

Comment: thanks, I got the another solution,
exec("convert audi_png.png -alpha set -channel RGBA -fuzz 20% -fill none -opaque #e10038 balloon_white22ff.png");

Comment: @bonzo can you solve this problem ? http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=22559
http://i49.tinypic.com/qp5vz7.png You can see in the image i just wish to keep two colors 
color 1 -#609018
color 2- #489000 and remove all rest colors.

Comment: The code I posted there will remove the red and black spots - including the black text. But what about any other images do they contain the same colours as a more complicated method may be required. exec("convert http://i49.tinypic.com/qp5vz7.png -fill white -fuzz 20% -opaque red -opaque black output1.jpg");